# Is there a way to switch network adapters using the network GUI?

Tags: networking, 20.04, kubuntu, gui, adapter

I am using an additional USB network adapter set to interface (wlo1) on my computer and I know there is a way to manually turn off my default interface (lo1) using the commandline but want to know if there is a way to switch network adapters in the GUI menu or if there is a network-manager application that can do so. I am using KDE as well. I know windows has a way to switch when a USB network adapter is inserted so idk if there is something similiar for Linux.

[Windows example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NRRh.png)

Comment: in KDE there is a [Plasma applet for NetworkManager](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/plasma-nm). Also you can install it by `sudo apt install plasma-nm`

Comment: I do have that already but no place for the adapters